# using the Google Play Billing Library and system does refund after 3 days for inapp product

Tags: in-app-billing, in-app, android-inapp-purchase

My app is using the Google Play Billing Library

```
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.3'
}
```

Everything works great, except for system does refund after 3 days for inapp product(SkuType.INAPP).

what is the possible wrong implementation of this issue?

I have contacted Google for support, said: "issue is in my APK". And then I checked my code again was nothing wrong.

Do I need to add "The Base64-encoded RSA public key" to the app? if so, how to implement it? I don't see any example of this.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Google Play Billing Library version 2.0 or newer, you must acknowledge all purchases within three days. Failure to properly acknowledge purchases results in those purchases being refunded. You can read more about how to implement acknowledging purchases in your app in the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#acknowledge